Unable to install Ubuntu 22.04 to dual boot with Windows 11
I've been trying my best to avoid making this post, but I'm unsure what I'm doing wrong here.
I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 alongside Windows 11. I have downloaded the ISO and verified it is correct. I used Rufus to flash a USB drive with the ISO, using the GPT partition scheme. I have turned off secure boot and fast boot via Windows settings and in my BIOS. I partitioned a 50GB section in my boot drive and left it unallocated.
I booted into Ubuntu using the USB drive and installed it. I left the default installation method and installed, which brought up a prompt saying the installer would reformat/repartition (I don't remember the exact terms used) my boot drive. However, once installation is complete and I restart and remove the USB when prompted, I can only boot into Windows, there is not the dual boot menu where I can choose my OS.
I am unsure what I am doing wrong here.
EDIT: Was unable to boot into "Try Ubuntu" space, so used "nomodeset" boot option to get in and install boot-repair. Pastebin link here: https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/3HP3z7KMF6/
============================== Boot Info Summary ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/nvme0n1.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No known boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

nvme0n1p1: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/Boot/fbx64.efi 
                       /efi/Boot/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/mmx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi 
                       /efi/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

nvme0n1p2: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

nvme0n1p3: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 8 or 10
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

nvme0n1p4: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

nvme0n1p5: _____________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  MSWIN4.1: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /efi/boot/bootx64.efi 
                       /efi/boot/grubx64.efi /efi/boot/mmx64.efi


================================ 2 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS on nvme0n1p5
OS#2:   Windows 8 or 10 on nvme0n1p3

================================ Host/Hardware =================================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Video: GA102 [GeForce RTX 3080 12GB] Intel Corporation EFI VGA from NVIDIA Corporation Intel Corporation
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS, jammy, x86_64)

===================================== UEFI =====================================

BIOS/UEFI firmware: 1.10(5.27) from American Megatrends International, LLC.
The firmware is EFI-compatible, and is set in EFI-mode for this live-session.
SecureBoot disabled (confirmed by mokutil).
BootCurrent: 0003
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0003,0000,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,c7001c4e-99df-4b6d-b705-fccf6692930d,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,c7001c4e-99df-4b6d-b705-fccf6692930d,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0003* UEFI:  USB DISK 3.0 PMAP, Partition 1 PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x14,0x0)/USB(23,0)/HD(1,GPT,da22d33c-69b7-449c-a173-2ea8280974c4,0x800,0x73557c0)..BO

64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/Boot/bootx64.efi
a9c517741ac31962d7feb152948ad1ee   nvme0n1p1/Boot/fbx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/Boot/mmx64.efi
a1da253696a304dce6b4668b70151c0e   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/grubx64.efi
a660182adef313615746a665966d2ccc   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/mmx64.efi
64349b3622c65f495a99dbf6102496e3   nvme0n1p1/ubuntu/shimx64.efi
e34c4135d75ce5708a2939554a087183   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
3029d8cf512ca3d3dec4bf64c2d0d20c   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgr.efi
b8796e68099026aabcebb8fcf75b21f6   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/cbmr_driver.efi
23837e7f81b5b729c2cc673d3da56273   nvme0n1p1/Microsoft/Boot/SecureBootRecovery.efi

============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

nvme0n1 : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has---ESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    has-win,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes
sda : is-GPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, no-os, no-wind,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
nvme0n1p3   : is-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p4   : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB
nvme0n1p5   : is-os,    64, apt-get,    signed grub-pc grub-efi ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    end-after-100GB
sda1    : no-os,    64, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   end-after-100GB

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : is---ESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p3   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p4   : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, recovery-or-hidden, no-bmgr,    notwinboot
nvme0n1p5   : isnotESP, fstab-has-goodEFI,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

nvme0n1p1   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p3   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p4   : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, nvme0n1
nvme0n1p5   : not--sepboot, with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, nvme0n1
sda1    : not--sepboot, no---boot,  part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  no--grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk nvme0n1: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: B978ACEB-D473-442C-9DED-EAB6C21232E3
              Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
nvme0n1p1       2048     206847     204800   100M EFI System
nvme0n1p2     206848     239615      32768    16M Microsoft reserved
nvme0n1p3     239616 1847420927 1847181312 880.8G Microsoft basic data
nvme0n1p4 1952278528 1953519615    1241088   606M Windows recovery environment
nvme0n1p5 1847420928 1952278527  104857600    50G Linux filesystem
Partition table entries are not in disk order.
Disk sda: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk identifier: 8CBF3EDB-40AA-4168-A496-11A76E25BB37
     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
sda1   2048 3907029134 3907027087  1.8T Microsoft basic data
Disk sdb: 57.67 GiB, 61920509952 bytes, 120938496 sectors
Disk identifier: A88E5E14-A319-4794-897B-B8BFAEC8E7E4
     Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
sdb1   2048 120938431 120936384 57.7G Microsoft basic data

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:2000GB:scsi:512:4096:gpt:ATA ST2000DM001-1ER1:;
1:1049kB:2000GB:2000GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
sdb:61.9GB:scsi:512:512:gpt: USB DISK 3.0:;
1:1049kB:61.9GB:61.9GB:fat32:Main Data Partition:msftdata;
nvme0n1:1000GB:nvme:512:512:gpt:Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB:;
1:1049kB:106MB:105MB:fat32:EFI system partition:boot, esp;
2:106MB:123MB:16.8MB::Microsoft reserved partition:msftres;
3:123MB:946GB:946GB:ntfs:Basic data partition:msftdata;
5:946GB:1000GB:53.7GB:ext4::;
4:1000GB:1000GB:635MB:ntfs::hidden, diag;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME        FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL             PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                              
└─sda1      ntfs     D0166229166210B0                     8ac86874-a813-4fb1-8321-2e986d357651 Second Hard Drive Basic data partition
sdb                                                                                                              
└─sdb1      vfat     17FA-2148                            da22d33c-69b7-449c-a173-2ea8280974c4 UBUNTU 22_0       Main Data Partition
nvme0n1                                                                                                          
├─nvme0n1p1 vfat     E630-D2C0                            c7001c4e-99df-4b6d-b705-fccf6692930d                   EFI system partition
├─nvme0n1p2                                               0f550da3-54bf-47bc-9b08-f88f26046146                   Microsoft reserved partition
├─nvme0n1p3 ntfs     B01631B216317A84                     9a5cd28b-9f31-491f-bc9d-028fc3c1b883                   Basic data partition
├─nvme0n1p4 ntfs     10C2CC04C2CBEBD2                     73f77e28-3d4a-4fbd-b2a0-ad3c05301d82                   
└─nvme0n1p5 ext4     4b306598-158b-4c8d-92c9-22227b899af3 762de024-d278-448a-8821-247bc1246ddf                   

Mount points (filtered): _______________________________________________________

                           Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/nvme0n1p1             63.4M  34% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p3            552.4G  37% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p3
/dev/nvme0n1p4             88.9M  85% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p4
/dev/nvme0n1p5             35.5G  22% /mnt/boot-sav/nvme0n1p5
/dev/sda1                   1.6T  14% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
/dev/sdb1                    53G   8% /cdrom
efivarfs                  133.8K  46% /sys/firmware/efi/efivars

Mount options (filtered): ______________________________________________________

/dev/nvme0n1p1            vfat            rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro
/dev/nvme0n1p3            fuseblk         ro,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p4            fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/nvme0n1p5            ext4            rw,relatime
/dev/sda1                 fuseblk         rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
/dev/sdb1                 vfat            ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

=================== nvme0n1p1/efi/ubuntu/grub.cfg (filtered) ===================

search.fs_uuid 4b306598-158b-4c8d-92c9-22227b899af3 root 
set prefix=($root)'/boot/grub'
configfile $prefix/grub.cfg

=================== nvme0n1p5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ====================

Ubuntu   4b306598-158b-4c8d-92c9-22227b899af3
Windows Boot Manager (on nvme0n1p1)   osprober-efi-E630-D2C0
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

======================== nvme0n1p5/etc/fstab (filtered) ========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p5 during installation
UUID=4b306598-158b-4c8d-92c9-22227b899af3 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=E630-D2C0  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

==================== nvme0n1p5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =====================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

================= nvme0n1p5: Location of files loaded by Grub ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 899.114753723 = 965.417115648  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1
 892.197826385 = 957.990121472  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 894.736881256 = 960.716410880  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-18-generic                  1
 892.197826385 = 957.990121472  boot/vmlinuz-6.5.0-28-generic                  1
 894.736881256 = 960.716410880  boot/vmlinuz.old                               1
 891.543941498 = 957.288017920  boot/initrd.img                                2
 917.247066498 = 984.886538240  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-18-generic               5
 891.543941498 = 957.288017920  boot/initrd.img-6.5.0-28-generic               2
 917.247066498 = 984.886538240  boot/initrd.img.old                            5

=================== nvme0n1p5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ===================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 18683 Dec 18  2022 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 43031 Dec 18  2022 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 14387 Dec 18  2022 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 13369 Dec 18  2022 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1372 Dec 18  2022 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   700 May 17  2023 35_fwupd
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Dec 18  2022 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   215 Dec 18  2022 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Try or Install Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings
Test memory

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1



Suggested repair: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub-efi of
nvme0n1p5,
using the following options:  nvme0n1p1/boot/efi
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s use-standard-efi-file

Final advice in case of suggested repair: ______________________________________

Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS entry (nvme0n1p1/efi/****/grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message) file) !
If your computer reboots directly into Windows, try to change the boot order in your UEFI firmware.
If your UEFI firmware does not allow to change the boot order, change the default boot entry of the Windows bootloader.
For example you can boot into Windows, then type the following command in an admin command prompt:
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\****\grub****.efi (**** will be updated in the final message)


Boot from the Ubuntu USB using the Try Ubuntu option. Install the utility boot-repair. Create and upload the Boot Info Summary file. Do not do any repairs yet.  Note down the upload location URL. Edit your question and add a link to the uploaded log file in your question.

What brand/model system? Can you boot Ubuntu from UEFI boot menu? Did you choose to install the optional restricted drivers, so the correct nVidia driver was installed as part of install? Or can you boot recovery mode in grub menu to install drivers?

GPU: Nvidia 3080 CPU: Intel i5-1300k Motherboard: MSI Z790P. I do get the option to boot into Ubuntu in the UEFI boot menu; it is under the "Use a device" option, even though I do not have the USB flash drive plugged in. Regarding the optional restricted drivers, is that the extra checkbox during installation about extra drivers and whatnot? I did check that in a previous install as I was trying this, but I don't believe I checked that for this install. I'm unsure how I could boot into grub menu? Would that be the same method as when I replaced "quicksplash" with "nomodeset", in that menu?

Out of curiosity I booted into Ubuntu under the "Use a device" option, but after a quick Ubuntu splash screen I was met with just a black screen.
